# Authenticate user after password reset in Django

Tags: django, django-authentication

I use standard Django view, password_reset_confirm(), to reset user's password. After user follows password reset link in the letter, he enters new password and then view redirects him to the site root:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', {
        'template_name': 'website/auth/password_reset_confirm.html',
        'post_reset_redirect': '/',
    }, name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

After Django redirects user, he is not authenticated. I don't want him to type password again, instead, I want to authenticate him right after he set new password.

To implement this feature, I created a delegate view. It wraps standard one and handles its output. Because standard view redirects user only if password reset succeeded, I check status code of response it returns, and if it's a redirect, retrieve user from DB again and authenticate him.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        views.password_reset_confirm_delegate, {
        'template_name': 'website/auth/password_reset_confirm.html',
        'post_reset_redirect': '/',
    }, name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

**views.py**

```
@sensitive_post_parameters()
@never_cache
def password_reset_confirm_delegate(request, **kwargs):
    response = password_reset_confirm(request, **kwargs)
    # TODO Other way?
    if response.status_code == 302:
        try:
            uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(kwargs['uidb64'])
            user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            pass
        else:
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, passwordless=True)
            login(request, user)
    return response
```

**backends.py**

```
class PasswordlessAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    """Log in to Django without providing a password.

    """
    def authenticate(self, username, passwordless=False):
        if not passwordless:
            return None
        try:
            return User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'website.backends.PasswordlessAuthBackend'
)
```

Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: Thank you for this. You helped me on how to get the user id decoding from the kwargs. You can get the password from the request's POST parameters, that way you don't have to implement a different authentication backend.

Comment: Can't you just pull the password out of the POST parameters?  Then you wouldn't need a password-less auth backend if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Vanilla Django

Since `password_reset_confirm` is not class-based-view, you cant cleanly customize it in any significant way without resorting to middleware-type tricks. Therefore what you are doing seems to be the most efficient way at the moment.

If django would be been passing `request` to the `SetPasswordForm` (similar to how DRF passes `request` to serializers), you could of overwritten the form's `save()` to login the user there however as now that is also not possible.

#### 3rd party packages

You can also look into other 3rd party libs which implement auth as class based views. From a quick google search, the most promising are:

- [django-password-reset](https://github.com/brutasse/django-password-reset). Seems to provide complete replacement for `auth.views` as class based views. You can overwrite [`form_valid`](https://github.com/brutasse/django-password-reset/blob/master/password_reset/views.py#L149-L156) in order to authenticate user.
- [django-class-based-auth-views](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-class-based-auth-views) (not complete)

Comment: Any example on how can we over-ride `form_valid` function.? It will be of huge help. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Starting Django 1.11 your can do this by using the class based view. You need to override the password_reset_confirm url to pass `post_reset_login=True` and `success_url` to [PasswordResetConfirmView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView):

```py
urlpatterns += [
 url(
   r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
      post_reset_login=True,
      success_url=reverse_lazy('studygroups_login_redirect')
    ),
    name='password_reset_confirm'
  ),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the existence of [reverse_lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy)!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works in Django 3.1