# django user logged out after password change

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue with Django users changing passwords - I have built a few production sites in Django, just none in about a year (or in 1.8), but I don't recall having this issue before.

**Summary**

When a user changes their password, the user is logged out, but the password is successfully changed.

**Details**

I have a view that allows a user to change a password, I am using standard django forms and the auth framework, and ***to stress: changing the password works, it just logs the user out so that they have to login again***.

I actually don't mind this terribly, I would prefer that the user be redirected to their dashboard with a message update, if i need to reauth the user in the code, then I will, just seems kind of clunky.

here is my view function:

```
@login_required
def user_change_password(request):
    """Allows a user to change their password"""

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SubscriberPasswordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                request.user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
                request.user.save()
            except Exception, err:
                print "Error changing password: {}".format(err)
                messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'The password could not be changed, please try again '
                                                              'later. This admins have been notified of this error.')
            else:
                #this outputs True
                print request.user.is_authenticated()

                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Your password has been changed successfully')
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/dashboard/")
    else:
        form = SubscriberPasswordForm()

    return render(request, "accounts/change-password.html", {"form": form})
```

So the password is changed, the user gets redirected to the dashboard page, the @login_required decorator then redirects them back to the login screen.

The password form is here, though it is pretty straightforward.

```
class SubscriberPasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    cpassword = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean_cpassword(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("cpassword")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
```

Comment: This is a good thing; and you should be doing this anyway. It was enabled by default in 1.7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My understanding is being logged out after password change is new in Django 1.7.  So you will need to re-auth user in your code as you said.

See Release Notes:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.7/#django-contrib-auth

*Here is the specific note:*
"The AbstractBaseUser.get_session_auth_hash() method was added and if your AUTH_USER_MODEL inherits from AbstractBaseUser, changing a user’s password now invalidates old sessions if the SessionAuthenticationMiddleware is enabled. See Session invalidation on password change for more details including upgrade considerations when enabling this new middleware."

See Documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change

Comment: ok thx - did not see that. I think 1.6 was actually the last version I used.

Answer (score 31):

For django 1.9:

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash

def password_change(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
```

The following fields must be supplied in the POST request:

- old_password
- new_password1
- new_password2

See detailed docs at [update_session_auth_hash](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change)

Answer (score 17):

**For Django 1.8**

Simply call `update_session_auth_hash` after `set_password` like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash

request.user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
update_session_auth_hash(request, request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

for Django 3, Django 1.8+ use this link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.update_session_auth_hash

or use this code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash

def password_change(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
    else:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 1.11 you can use `post_reset_login=True`. See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47535448/10039005